# Error Undefined property: en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

pague un sistemas php y al subirlo a hosting, no puedo lograr configurarlo, quien me lo vendio, no contesta mis mensajes ni emails, y teoricamente tenia soperte. El error es el siguiente:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Mapos::$session

Filename: controllers/mapos.php

Line Number: 12
```

Mi código es el siguiente

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mapos extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mapos_model','',TRUE);
        
    }

    public function index() {
        if((!$this->session->userdata('session_id')) || (!$this->session->userdata('logado'))){
            redirect('mapos/login');
        }

        $this->data['ordens'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsAbertas();
        $this->data['produtos'] = $this->mapos_model->getProdutosMinimo();
        $this->data['os'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsEstatisticas();
        $this->data['estatisticas_financeiro'] = $this->mapos_model->getEstatisticasFinanceiro();
        $this->data['menuPainel'] = 'Painel';
        $this->data['view'] = 'mapos/painel';
        $this->load->view('tema/topo',  $this->data);
      
    }

    public function minhaConta() {
        if((!$this->session->userdata('session_id')) || (!$this->session->userdata('logado'))){
            redirect('mapos/login');
        }

        $this->data['usuario'] = $this->mapos_model->getById($this->session->userdata('id'));
        $this->data['view'] = 'mapos/minhaConta';
        $this->load->view('tema/topo',  $this->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que ver si en: `aplication/config/autoload.php`, esta la session habilitada

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cargar la libreria, mejor si lo haces en el constructor.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```